# Daemon process how to make to auto run while bootup

Tags: c, linux

Clubbing few questions here.

I have a daemon process.

**What i need?**

1) How can i make sure, the daemon process is invoked while the system is booted up.

2)  Do we have any standard rule for the following Or it is left to the requirement?

```
2.a  Behavior of the daemon while it receives the abort, kill signals. does it
     need to restart itself?
```

Kindly provide hints.

Comment: It depends on what you call the system boot. For me the system boot is not concerned with daemon but with kernel modules / extensions.

Answer (score 4):

1. It depends on your distro.  There are things that `init` does it when it starts -- scripts it invokes, et cetera -- you'd need to hook into one of those or -- more optimally -- provide one yourself (try Googling "*init script*" along with the name of the distro you're targeting).
2. It would be highly undesirable -- bordering on malicious -- for an aborted/killed/etc. daemon to automatically restart itself.  That defies the point of aborting/killing/etc. a process -- daemon or not.  If the user wants to kill and restart a process -- daemon or not -- they can kill it and then restart it.  If the user wants the daemon to reparse its config etc. there's SIGHUP for that.

Comment: +1 for "bordering on malicious." I'd consider any userland process that didn't respect a `SIGTERM` to be malware, and more than likely it would be receiving a `kill -9` within short order. Luckily, AFAIK one can't ignore `SIGKILL`. (: